The proof of Generalized Cauchy Integral Formula
Backgourd:

The complex function $f(z)$ is analytic on a closed circle
$\overline D(z_0,r)$. Prove that:
$$f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi\text{i}}\int_{\partial D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{2}}\mathrm{d}z$$

We know that $f^{}(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi\text{i}}\int_{\partial D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{}}\mathrm{d}z$, if we can "somehow" change the order of derivative: $$\tag{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z}_{|z=z_0}=\frac{1}{2\pi\text{i}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}_{|z=z_0}\int_{\partial D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^{}}\mathrm{d}\zeta"="\frac{1}{2\pi\text{i}}\int_{\partial D(z_0,r)}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^{2}}\mathrm{d}\zeta,$$
then we are done. To prove the order can be changed, let $z_0+re^{\text{i}t}$ be the parametric representation of the circle $D(z_0,r)$. We also know:
$$2\pi f(z_0)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{\text{i}t})\mathrm{d}t\Rightarrow f'(z_0)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}_{|z=z_0}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{\text{i}t})\mathrm{d}t$$
If the order can be changed, then $$\tag{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}_{|z=z_0}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{\text{i}t})\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\partial f(z_0+re^{\text{i}t})}{\partial z}_{|z=z_0}\mathrm{d}t$$
But it seems to be miss something in $(2)$. What should I do if I want to solve my question by proving the odrer can be changed?
And here my textbook prove a lemma without showing the details of how to use the lemma to prove.

What should I do to use the lemma to prove  it?

There are several instances of holomorphic differentiation under the integral being discussed on the site, e.g my answer here. Alternatively you can expand the denominator as a power series and exchange the series with an integral (using uniform convergence of the series) then easily read off the various derivatives (which I wrote in detail here); in fact this approach also shows that every holomorphic function on an annulus has a Laurent expansion.

For differentiation under the integral, even if you do not know about the dominated convergence theorem used in the link, you could try (with more effort) to prove a more elementary variant under stronger hypotheses like uniform convergence of the difference quotients; I leave this to you.

hmmm ok actually your very first step itself needs to be improved. While what you wrote using Cauchy’s formula for $f(z_0)$ is true, in order to differentiate, you need a formula for all $z$ near $z_0$, namely (by deforming the contour slightly) $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta-z_0|=r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z},d\zeta$. Notice the denominator has $z$ not $z_0$, while the contour is a circle centered at $z_0$. Anyway, your approach (2) doesn’t really seem to work (atleast I don’t see right away how to make it work) because the derivative will land on the $f$ inside the integral.

@peek-a-boo Thanks a lot!Your comment reminds me of $\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w-z|=R}f(w)\frac{dw}{(w-z-h)(w-z)}$,and let$h\to 0$.But can i use the dominated convergence theorem here?Since $|f(w)|\le M$ is bounded and let $|h|<\frac{R}{2} $,thus$|w-z-h|\ge ||w-z|-|h||=R-|h|\ge \frac R2$,then$|f(w)\frac{1}{(w-z-h)(w-z)}|\le \frac{2M}{R^2}$

Yup, and the constant function $2M/R^2$ of course has finite arclength along the circle, so you can apply DCT now.
